# Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred in jspf. Which JSP?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jsp-fragments

The tomcat log throws the following error:

> Sep 15, 2014 7:34:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /XYZ.jspf Obj1 cannot
>   be resolved.
>
> Stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:476)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:138)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

I am unable to determine the jsp that has the problem.

I can do a manual search and locate it by the eclipse jsp validation,
but **how do I get the log to tell me the jsp's name**.
I have enabled debug logging for tomcat (WTP).

Comment: Looks like XYZ.jspf. Considering the message `Obj1 cannot be resolved.`, perhaps you need to see what JSPs include that fragment but do not create a variable of that name?

Comment: That I know; but how can I get the log to spit it out..